# How to get the cmd command output in c# to a lable

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a code for run cmd commands from c# form application. Now I want to get the output of the cmd to a **lable in winform.** I wrote a code. but it is giving me following error

[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F42Mi.png)

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: **StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.**

how to fix it? this is my **original code.**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startiNFO = new  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

    startiNFO.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startiNFO.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startiNFO.Arguments = "/C ipconfig";
    startiNFO.UseShellExecute = false;

    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    process.StartInfo = startiNFO;

    process.Start();

    string outp = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    MessageBox.Show(outp);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of `process.WaitForExit();` do something like this

The complete code for your function would look something like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C ipconfig";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.Start();
    string q = "";
    while(!process.HasExited)
    {
        q += process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
    label1.text = q;
    MessageBox.Show(q);
}
```

Comment: Can I assign q to a label1.text ?

Comment: string outp = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); should be removed ?

Comment: OK. Thank you.I'll try it and reply you.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.

Comment: What I want to do now?

Comment: Thank you my friend. It's Working.

Comment: now I want to hide the cmd window. Please can you edit the code for it?

Comment: You can try using `process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`

Comment: Happy to help ... Happy Coding :)

Comment: How to display the selected part of output? as a example ping, only data loss amount ? help me

Comment: You can ask a different question for that with all the details. And also post the link to the question here

Comment: I can't post a question. they told me after 3 days